# Cross-origin Ajax requests don't work in Opera and IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, cross-domain

I am using this page - http://ecmazing.com/cors.html - to make a cross-origin Ajax request to this resource: http://hacheck.tel.fer.hr/xml.pl

It works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but doesn't in IE9 and Opera.

The code:

```
var pdata = {'textarea': 'test'};

$.post('http://hacheck.tel.fer.hr/xml.pl', pdata, function(data, status, xhr) {
    output.value = xhr.responseText;
});
```

(The expected result is an XML code string.)

**See for yourself:** http://ecmazing.com/cors.html

In IE9 and Opera, the `error` handler of the XHR object executes and this error object is passed in:

```
{
    readyState: 4,
    status: 0,
    statusText: 'error'
}
```

As you can see, this error object doesn't reveal much information.

How can I make it work in IE9 and Opera?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the entry for [cors at whencaniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors).

For Internet Explorer CORS is "Supported somewhat in IE8 and IE9 using the XDomainRequest object", so you need to use an alternate object to use it.

Opera simply doesn't support it.

If you need cross-domain Ajax in Opera, then use JSON-P.

Comment: OK, that rules out Opera. But I thought jQuery uses that XDomainRequest object internally... I'll go check out jQuery's source code..

Comment: No, `XDomainRequest` is nowhere mentioned in jQuery's source code. I guess, jQuery just doesn't support cross-domain Ajax requests in IE9 and Opera at this point...

Comment: JSON-P doesn't apply for POST or other requests.

Comment: @Quentin  note the cookies are not supported on IE8/9 XDomainRequest

Answer (score 6):

I got so frustrated trying to use CORS with IE and jQuery, I wrote a [library](https://github.com/Malvolio/ie.xhr) to smooth over the worst parts.

Yeah, Microsoft's shortage of cash and manpower have kept them from making their browsers properly CORS-compliant in the seven short years they've had to do it in, but I still prefer CORS to JSONP, which, frankly, is a hack.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is a solution that works for IE.](http://saltybeagle.com/2009/09/cross-origin-resource-sharing-demo/)