# $.getJSON is return a file with IE and Opera browsers

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

$.getJSON are returning a file with IE and Opera browsers (Firefox, Chrome... works fine).

The code is this:

```
$.getJSON("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&osm_type=N&bounded=1&limit=100&viewbox=-5.667593479156494,43.54767717445222,-5.656242370605469,43.54280902999833&q=Restaurants",
{
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
},
function(data) {
    var ind = 0;
    $.each(data, function(i, pos_reg){
       alert("Recovery " + i++ + " row");
    });
})
.error(function() {       
    alert("Was an error");
});
```

I think the problem is the Http header returned from the server.
If I paste the [URL](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&osm_type=N&bounded=1&limit=100&viewbox=-5.667593479156494,43.54767717445222,-5.656242370605469,43.54280902999833&q=Restaurants) on Firefox or Chrome, I see the JSON respond.
If I paste the URL on IE and Opera, they tries download the JSON respond as file.

I tried someting like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});
```

But same result :(

Any idea please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try get simple get and eval returning data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the answer to the question. **The real question** (the original question is vague) is how to make crossdomain ajax call in Opera and Internet Explorer.

Duplicate to [Cross-origin Ajax requests don't work in Opera and IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947821/cross-origin-ajax-requests-dont-work-in-opera-and-ie9) as linked by the topic starter.

---

I know that Opera doesn't open JSON by default, it indeed tries to download the file. You can change this in the settings: "Settings" > "Advanced" > "Downloads", now search for *json*, if you don't find it, you can create a new type. Now fill in *application/json* and set it to open with Opera (I added also *text/json* because sometimes websites return this content-type). Here is a screen capture of those screens:

[image: Opera json download settings]

I guess that you can do something similar in Internet Explorer as well.
EDIT: I found the solution for Internet Explorer. It has been answered before on SO, so I will just post here the link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2492211 .

Comment: Ok, the problem you are having is due to security violation (cross domain request). Your question itself wasn't clear at all. You'll have to use JSONP to solve this.

Comment: Could be it! @Styxxy :D But... Is it normal that in Firefox & Chrome works perfect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947821/cross-origin-ajax-requests-dont-work-in-opera-and-ie9 Thanks Styxxy!!