# JSON/JQuery .getJSON() doesn't work in IE8/IE9

Tags: jquery, json

I don't know if it's due the **JSON** or **JQuery .getJSON()** but this code **doesn't work** in **IE8/IE9**.

I'm trying to fetch some data from *foursquare* and display it.

It works normal in Chrome,Firefox,Safari,Opera and IE10.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function){

    var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4dab1ba55da3ba8a479999b2?oauth_token=ZKLARA2MZVA4VXES3VTMP2XJOVXE1X3OBJMBXMDFAB1NR0V4&v=20130305";

    $.getJSON(url, function(response){

        do{
            var countNum = (response.response.venue.tips.count)-1;
            var randomGroupNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*countNum)+0);
        }while(typeof(response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum])==="undefined");

        var countItemNum = response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum].count;
        var randomItemNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*countItemNum)+0); 

        var mayorName = response.response.venue.mayor.user.firstName;
        var mayorSurname = response.response.venue.mayor.user.lastName;
        var mayorCount = response.response.venue.mayor.count;
        var mayorPic = "https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs"+response.response.venue.mayor.user.photo.suffix;

        var text = response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum].items[randomItemNum].text;
        var time = new Date((response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum].items[randomItemNum].createdAt)*1000);

        var userName = response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum].items[randomItemNum].user.firstName;
        var userSurname = response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum].items[randomItemNum].user.lastName;
        var userPic ="https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs"+response.response.venue.tips.groups[randomGroupNum].items[randomItemNum].user.photo.suffix;    

        $("#mayor_img").attr("src", mayorPic);
        $("#mayor_name").append("<span style='font-weight:bold;'>"+mayorName+" "+mayorSurname+"</span>");
        $("#mayor_check_in").append("<span>"+mayorCount+" check-ins in last 60 days</span>");

        $("#last_tip_img").attr("src", userPic);
        $("#last_tip_name").append("<span style='font-weight:bold;'>"+userName+" "+userSurname+"</span>");
        $("#last_tip_comment").append("<span>"+text+"</span>");
    });
});
```

[Here is the fiddle of my JS and HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/PhYUq/).

Is this due the IE8/IE9 or something else?

Comment: Do you have an error on the browsers on which it doesn't work ?

Comment: @dystroy it shows no errors.

Comment: If you are using jQuery > 1.5 you could use the `fail` method to see what went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.getJSON not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315211/getjson-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use JSONP instead of JSON, it works in IE9. Simply add `&callback=?` to the end of your foursquare URL and their API will deliver JSONP:

```
var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4dab1ba55da3ba8a479999b2?oauth_token=ZKLARA2MZVA4VXES3VTMP2XJOVXE1X3OBJMBXMDFAB1NR0V4&v=20130305&callback=?";
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhYUq/1/)

I couldn't get the fiddle to load in IE8, but that is probably just a problem with JSFiddle, since you found that this fix does work in your real page.

Here's what is going on: your `$.ajax()` call is making a [cross-domain XMLHttpRequest](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross-domain+XMLHttpRequest), which traditionally was not allowed at all by browsers. [JSONP](https://www.google.com/search?q=jsonp) is a workaround that solves this problem in all browsers, past, present, and future, by enclosing the JSON data inside a JavaScript function call which is loaded using a `<script>` tag instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. You can see this function call when you look at the data returned by foursquare when you use JSONP. Since `<script>` tags can be loaded from any domain, this gets past the cross-domain limitation.

JSONP has some disadvantages, though:

1. The web service you're calling needs to support it. This one does, but not all do.
2. There is a security risk: if the service you're calling gets compromised, it could inject malicious JavaScript into your page.

More recently, browsers started to support [cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://www.google.com/search?q=cors). If the web service supports CORS, then you can use `XMLHttpRequest` across domains with some additional setup in the JavaScript code.

jQuery's `$.ajax()` does this automatically for IE10 and other modern browsers, but [IE8 and IE9 had a different way of supporting CORS](https://www.google.com/search?q=ie9+cors) using an `XDomainRequest` object. jQuery does not support this object.

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947821/cross-origin-ajax-requests-dont-work-in-opera-and-ie9) has some further discussion along with a link to a [CORS library for IE8/9](https://github.com/Malvolio/ie.xhr) that can be used to add CORS capability to jQuery for those browsers. I haven't tested it myself, but it may be an alternative to JSONP if you'd like to use CORS instead.

One thing I notice in the instructions for using this library is that it appears that it will try to use the `XDomainRequest` in IE10 and greater where it isn't necessary, as well as in IE8/9 where it is needed. This may be OK, or you may want to add a version check or something to only use it in the older versions.

Comment: Works both in IE8 and IE9. Didn't know that IE9> had problems with JSON. Thanks.

Comment: That's because it's a cross-domain request. JSON works fine with any version of IE when you're loading from the same domain, but not across domains. I updated the answer with some more information and another possible approach using a CORS library for IE8/9.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. :)